# Como colocar loop apenas em uma parte do comando? E que fosse possível sair dela

Tags: python, loop

Oi, estou criando um comando de um inimigo que é um esqueleto com uma besta, ele possui dois ataques mas vou mostrar apenas um ataque que é o tiro de besta dele.
Estou utilizando o python para programar, e esse é um dos meus primeiros comandos que faço, felizmente não tem um erro no código, mas queria fazer uma coisa que não consigo fazer.
Ele tem atributos assim como a chance de causar crítico, eu controlo eles manualmente pois eu serei o mestre e irei controlar os inimigos para derrotar os jogadores.

Nessa parte do comando é possível ver que há uma pergunta sobre marcação, pois no meu rpg ele causa dano extra contra inimigos marcados, caso eu coloque 3 ou outros números que não encaixam, o código recebe um erro, queria saber algum método de ao responder colocando um número que não encaixa na pergunta (1 e 2) queria que ele repetisse a pergunta até escolher um desses dois números.
Marcação = int(input("O inimigo está marcado? (1)Sim / (2)Não"))

```
print("O esqueleto acertou")
    print()
    time.sleep(1)
    Dano = random.randint(4, 8)
    print("O dano foi de:",Dano)
    Resistencia = int(input("Quantos pontos o jogador diminui o dano?"))
    Dano_Final = Dano - Resistencia
    print("O dano total foi de:")
    print(Dano_Final)
    Marcação = int(input("O inimigo está marcado? (1)Sim / (2)Não"))

    if Marcação == 1:
        Marcado = Dano_Final / 100
        Marcado1 = Marcado * 25
        Marcado2 = Marcado1 + Dano_Final
        print()
        print("O dano total foi de:")
        print(Marcado2)
        CRT1 = random.randint(1, 100)
        if CRT1 <= Crítico1:
            time.sleep(1)
            print("CRÍTICO!")
            Dano_Crítico = Marcado2 * 2
            print()
            time.sleep(1)
            print("O dano do crítico foi de:")
            print(Dano_Crítico)


        elif Marcação == 2:
            CRT1 = random.randint(1, 100)
            if CRT1 <= Crítico1:
                time.sleep(1)
                print("CRÍTICO!")
                Dano_Crítico = Dano_Final * 2
                print()
                time.sleep(1)
                print("O dano do crítico foi de:")
                print(Dano_Crítico)
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode aplicar o loop while antes do if e após a declaração da variável marcação:

```
Marcação = int(input("O inimigo está marcado? (1)Sim / (2)Não"))

while Marcação >= 3:
    Marcação = int(input("O inimigo está marcado? (1)Sim / (2)Não"))
```

Uma outra opção seria declarar uma lista com as opções aceitas, da seguinte forma:

```
Marcação = int(input("O inimigo está marcado? (1)Sim / (2)Não"))

lista = [1, 2]

while Marcação not in lista:
    Marcação = int(input("O inimigo está marcado? (1)Sim / (2)Não"))
```

Comment: Quem votou positivo nessa resposta poderia informar porque colocou em evidência códigos que violam o [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/137387) e que causam uma falha catastrófica caso o usuário digite algo que não possa ser convertido em inteiro? https://ideone.com/sIDhHU e https://ideone.com/CW757o

Answer (score 1):

A partir do Python 3.8 você pode criar um loop que faça o uso do [operador de atribuição walrus](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) de maneira possa filtrar valores inválidos digitados pelo usuário.

O algoritmo é simples,

- dentro de um laço `while`
- crie uma expressão de atribuição para entrada do usuário, ainda sem  converter para inteiro ou outro tipo.
- verifique se entrada do está ou não dentro de uma lista contendo a possível faixa de valores:

  - caso sim, a entrada esteja dentro da possível abandona o loop.
  - caso não, é realizado algum código de contenção e laço é reiterado.
- fora do laço `while` então faça conversão de tipos para a entrada do usuário.

```python
Marcação:= input("O inimigo está marcado? (1)Sim / (2)Não: ")
```

```python
while (Marcação:= input("O inimigo está marcado? (1)Sim / (2)Não: ")) not in ["1","2"]: 
  print("Valor inválido")
Marcação = int(Marcação)
print(f"Opção digitada {Marcação}")
```

Resultando:

```
O inimigo está marcado? (1)Sim / (2)Não: 12
Valor inválido
O inimigo está marcado? (1)Sim / (2)Não: 3
Valor inválido
O inimigo está marcado? (1)Sim / (2)Não: A
Valor inválido
O inimigo está marcado? (1)Sim / (2)Não: 
Valor inválido
O inimigo está marcado? (1)Sim / (2)Não: 1
Opção digitada 1
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/marcacao1#main.py)</sup>

Para versões de Python 3 anteriores a versão 3.8 que não contam com o operador de atribuição walrus o algoritmo sofre umas mudanças:

- abra um loop sem condição de parada, `while True:`
- dentro do laço, atribua a entrada do usuário a uma variável, converter para inteiro ou outro tipo.
- verifique se entrada do está ou não dentro de uma lista contendo a possível faixa de valores:

  - caso sim, a entrada esteja dentro da possível abandona o loop.
  - caso não, é realizado algum código de contenção e laço é reiterado.
- fora do laço `while` então faça conversão de tipos para a entrada do usuário.

```
while True: 
   Marcação = input("O inimigo está marcado? (1)Sim / (2)Não: ")
   if Marcação in ["1", "2"]: break
   print("Valor inválido")
Marcação = int(Marcação)
print("Opção digitada ", Marcação)
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/marcacao2#main.py)</sup>